# How to disable onbeforeunload at Firefox 5

Tags: javascript, firefox

I want to disable `onbeforeunload` in Firefox browser. Don't tell me to disable JavaScript. I just want to disable this dialog box from appearing.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

one thing i do when some annoying website run some stuff like that is overriding the functions. let me give you an example.

in most cases if `onbeforeunload` has been defined using this method:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
   ....
}
```

You can override it using firebug console the same way

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {} // blank function
```

Note: I have encountered some script that use `self.close` with a timer that is also very annoying for a slow reader like me. here is my solution

```
window.close = function() {} // blank function
```

simply override closing the window.

I hope this answers your question

Comment: I want this feature to be disabled every page i visit